# Implementing MADD instruction in a multicycle processor

Tags: processor

I need to modify the datapath of a multicycle processor shown here http://kujo.cs.pitt.edu/index.php/Image:Datapath.png with a multiplier and HI LO registers to enable it to perform the instruction

```
MADD rs,rt
```

with the following effect

```
HI,LO ← HI,LO + R[rs] × R[rt]
```

The multiplier forms the product in an internal 64-bit register, and the result is taken in the form of a high and low 32-bit halfs. I'm having trouble defining the control signals that are needed for this to work and actually understanding the way the instruction should be performed. Can anyone help me?

Comment: There is only single register write port in the datapath. So, you can't store the result in single CPU tick (assuming 32-bit ports). So, you should write one half in first tick (after getting result) and then write second half in the tick two. Also, you should keep pipeline stalled for extra tick (before results are written into register file).